# Adding text to the completed dialog of an NSIS installer

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm trying to add text or add an extra dialog at the end of an NSIS installer. So, to clarify, when the install has completed successfully I want to show some information.

[image]

I've seen various examples that touch on it but none seem to actually present a solution.

Does anyone have any info that can help?

Comment: Why can't you use the finish page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using the MUI so you can just customize the finish page text to fit your needs:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TITLE "Custom title"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TITLE_3LINES
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TEXT "Custom text blah blah blah$\r$\nblah blah blah$\r$\nblah blah blah$\r$\nblah blah blah$\r$\nblah blah blah$\r$\n"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
```

And if that is unacceptable for whatever reason, you can create a totally custom page:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
AutoCloseWindow True ; Automatically move on from the InstFiles page
Page Custom MyFinishPageCreate
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

!include nsDialogs.nsh

Function MyFinishPageCreate
!ifdef MUI_SYSVERSION
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Title" "Sub-title"
!endif
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Blah blah blah"
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 30u 100% -30u "More blah blah blah"
Pop $0
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

If you want to display text directly on the InstFiles page you have to create a label control manually:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh

Page InstFiles "" InstFilesShow

Var MyText
Function InstFilesShow
; Cannot use CreateWindowEx in a Section, must do it in the show callback
FindWindow $1 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT # Finds the inner dialog
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i${__NSD_Label_EXSTYLE},t "${__NSD_Label_CLASS}",t "Text goes here",i${__NSD_Label_STYLE},i10,i100,i300,i200,p$1,p0,p0,p0)p.s'
Pop $MyText
ShowWindow $MyText 0
SendMessage $1 ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $2
SendMessage $MyText ${WM_SETFONT} $2 1
FunctionEnd

Section
${IfNot} ${Abort}
    ShowWindow $MyText 1
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks Anders, I'll give this a go and report back!